# Why do we add "de" in "éprouver de la joie"?

Tags: prépositions, verbes, partitif

I'm a little bit confused to why "de" is added in:

> Éprouver de la joie.

I thought "éprouver" is systematically followed by "de" but in this example (from Collins dictionary), we don't add it:

> Qu'est-ce que tu éprouves à ce moment-là?
>
> **Not**
>
> <s>Qu’est-ce que tu en éprouves ?</s>
>
> Or
>
> <s>De quoi est-ce que tu éprouves?</s>

I also thought that "Joie" is generally preceded by "de" but in a lot of examples I found online, it's only preceded by "la":

> Ces réunions se passent toujours dans la joie.

Comment: *article partitif* (du/de la/des) - it is like saying *some*, like in *some water* vs. *all the water*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***De la*** is not a preposition in your sentence but a [partitive article](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de/1).

The verb ***éprouver*** is not necessarily followed by ***de***:

> ***J'éprouve une joie** intense à ce moment-là.* (indefinite article)

> ***J'éprouve la joie** de la jardinière qui voit son travail porter ses fruits.* [Savante folle](https://savantefolle.wordpress.com/2021/08/) (definite article)

> *Devant ses plans naïfs, et si sincères, **j’éprouve joie et admiration**, la fraîcheur de ses idées me ferait presque croire qu’un monde meilleur est possible* [Enfant végé](http://enfantvege.canalblog.com/archives/2017/02/03/34887987.html) (zero article)

What precedes *joie* depends on what *joie* it is about:

1. Some amount of joy: *de la joie*
2. A given joy: *la joie (+ complement)*
3. Some joy: *une joie (+ adjective)*

Comment: True, but this doesn't answer why you can't just éprouver *la* joie. I feel you can't instinctively, but I couldn't explain why when I read this question. Compare a Daniel Lavoie lyric about finding Nirvana and losing it again, « que ce soit noyé dans la tristesse, ou bien perdu dans l'allégresse ». Why does the definite work there but not here? Or could both definite and indefinite be possible in the cases?

Comment: @LukeSawczak It can definitely be followed by *la* too: ***j’éprouve la joie** de la jardinière qui voit son travail porter ses fruits.* (https://savantefolle.wordpress.com/2021/08/)

Comment: Well, of course, but that's the definite of the genitive, rather than just definite on its own. I take it you can't just « éprouver la joie » or « la tristesse », then? What about « que ce soit noyé dans de la tristesse » ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak It would be possible to say *J'éprouve la joie* but only if that precise joy has already been mentioned so that wouldn't be very different from my example. *Joie* and *éprouver* are not that different from *eau* and *boire*: *Je bois de l'eau*, *Je bois l'eau de la fontaine*, *Je bois une eau qui a été aromatisée au citron*.

Comment: @4469766572736974C3A9 *Éprouver* confirme la capacité à ressentir puisqu'il s'agit de la perception elle-même.

Comment: @jlliagre I'm trying to convince myself that feelings should be treated as uncountable quantities like rice and water—  which are only measurable through grams, kilos, etc., which isn't the case with feelings ofc— but it's really hard! I guess it's just how French works :)

Comment: @Manar Feelings are only measurable by intensity/level. They are also uncountable in English : [joy](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/joy), [sorrow](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/sorrow)

Comment: Réf : "Peut-être dans le sens de « capacité formelle à ressentir » ou est-ce que dire _j'éprouve de la joie_ permet aussi de signifier ça ?"./ Ouais, donc ce serait comme une espèce de barbarisme. _Je suis capable de ressentir la joie_ est-il acceptable d'abord ?